# -bash: /usr/local/bin/rbenv: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied shows up everytime I try to use npm

Tags: node.js, npm, env

Everytime I try to use npm I get the error above. Python works fine on my computer but npm and node never work.

Comment: what has this got to do with python?

Comment: It probably doesnt but I have tried everything I know and cannot solve the issue so I am not sure what it has to do with

Comment: so you type `npm` in bash and you get that error?

Comment: You should try at http://superuser.com; one odd thing is that your error message mentions `rbenv`, which is used for managing multiple _Ruby_ versions.

Comment: yes when I type npm that is the error that is spit out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message you're getting suggests that **executable script `/usr/local/bin/rbenv` has a shebang line specifying executable `/usr/bin/env` (`#!/usr/bin/env ...`).**

The fact that it says **`Permission denied` means that, for some reason, `/usr/bin/env` is *not executable***, or at least not *executable by you*.

This is **highly unusual**, because `/usr/bin/env` is a frequently used standard utility. I would start investigating there, such as by running `ls -l /usr/bin/env` to see the permissions.

More broadly, the **question is why [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) - a utility for managing multiple *Ruby* environments - is involved here at all**.

I **suggest deactivating it at least temporarily while troubleshooting** - comment out the line that loads `rbenv` in your shell's profile/initialization file (in Bash: `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` - see https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell), then open a new terminal window.

Finally, some **background info on how `npm` is *normally* launched** on a Unix system:

- `npm` is a symlink located in your `$PATH` that points to an executable script named `npm-cli.js`.
- `npm-cli.js`, despite containing JavaScript, actually uses `#!/bin/sh` as its shebang line, which means that the *shell* (`sh`) *initially* executes the file.
- The 2nd line in `npm-cli.js` is in fact the *only* line that `sh` executes:

  - `` // 2>/dev/null; exec "`dirname "$0"`/node" "$0" "$@" ``
  - The line starts with `//` so that *node* later ignores it (since, in JavaScript, it is a *comment*), given that the line's sole purpose is to invoke *node*.
  - From the *shell*'s perspective, `//` is an attempt to run `//` as a *command*, which invariably fails, so `2>/dev/null` is appended to suppress the error message.
  - `` exec "`dirname "$0"`/node" "$0" "$@" `` then effectively relays invocation of the script at hand to the `node` executable:

    - `exec` replaces the running `sh` instance with the command specified.
    - `` "`dirname "$0"`/node"` `` specifies the *node* executable as residing in the same directory as the the `npm` *symlink* (which makes sense, given that both `node` and `npm` are always installed in the same directory).
    - `$0` refers to the script itself (the `npm` symlink)
    - `"$@"` simply passes all arguments passed to `npm` through.
- My guess is that the reason for this indirect invocation is to ensure that the `node` executable that is used to execute the `npm` script is from the *same* Node.js version. If a simple `#!/usr/bin/env node` shebang were used, then whatever `node` executable comes *first* in the `$PATH` would be used.